# Организовать схему CI/CD на Postgres

Tags: laravel, postgresql, phpunit

### Кратко

Есть несколько проектов на Laravel + MySQL + автотесты на PHPUnit. Теперь все это нужно перевезти на Postres, и я не понимаю как правильно раздать гранты CI-пользователю в этой РСУБД.

### Развернуто

Сейчас есть автоматическое тестирование на MySQL, для чего используется отдельный пользователь `ci-test`, которому разрешено практически все на базах данных `ci-test-*`. Базы заводятся вручную, но выдавать каждый раз права этому пользователю не нужно - работает "звездочка".

Теперь я хочу сделать похожую систему авто-тестирования на Postgres. Вот список требований, пожеланий и понимания как это сделать наилучшим образом:

- один пользователь `ci-test`
- одна схема `ci_test` на которую выдать по-максимуму гранты для `ci-test`
- несколько сервисов, который могут гонять тесты одновременно, то есть нужна куча БД
- и как следствие, такое пожелание: грант на создание баз данных вида `ci-test-*`, например `ci-test-shop-1`, `ci-test-shop-2`

Должно получиться так:

1. Запускается тест, который создает базу данных `ci-test-...`. Скрипт это уже умеет делать, тут больше вопрос - как ограничить его возможности через гранты.
2. Запускает миграция, которая создает необходимую структуру таблиц в БД, причем `search_path=ci_test`
3. Собственно, тест

### Что я делал, но не получилось

```sql
CREATE USER "ci-test" WITH PASSWORD 'ci-test';
CREATE SCHEMA "ci_test" AUTHORIZATION "ci-test";
CREATE DATABASE "ci-test-shop-1"; -- тут я на всякий случай сам создал БД

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA "ci_test" GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO "ci-test";
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA "ci_test" GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO "ci-test";
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA "ci_test" GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCES TO "ci-test";
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA "ci_test" GRANT ALL ON FUNCTIONS TO "ci-test";
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA "ci_test" GRANT ALL ON ROUTINES TO "ci-test";
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA "ci_test" GRANT ALL ON TYPES TO "ci-test";
```

Сейчас тест не работает: `password authentication failed for user "ci-test"`. Я догадываюсь, что нужно навесить гранты на `ci-test-shop-1`, но вот хочется сделать это каким-то шаблонным способом через "звездочку".